# What is the purpose of a Key in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

What is the the purpose of the key in linq? I am unsure on what is the purpose of it? What it does? How it affects the way the code runs?

```
else if (statType.Equals("Stat07"))
{
    //Score Stats by School

    {
        q = from t in dbsRound
            orderby t.RoundNumber
            group t by t.Contestant.School into g
            select new
            {
                School = g.Key,
                MaxScore = (from gr in g select gr.ScoreTotal).Max(),
                MinScore = (from gr in g select gr.ScoreTotal).Min(),
                AverageScore = (from gr in g select gr.ScoreTotal).Average()
            };
        GvStats.DataSource = q.ToList<dynamic>();

    }
}
```

Comment: It tells you the property by which you have "grouped" the data. When you use `group by` clause or `GroupBy` in method syntax, it returns `IEnumerable<TKey,T>` in which the `TKey` is the type of property by which you have applied grouping.

Comment: You have grouped your data by something, in this case by school, so the key holds the school name.

Comment: The key is the object that is used in the 'group' method.   It can be used to produce a dictionary object Dictionary<string,string> where the key is the first string.

Answer (score 3):

The key is the thing that is common in your group.

For example if you have a sequence of words and want to group all words on their first letter, then you have a group with words that start with the letter 'a', and a group with words that start with the letter 'b' etc.

Or if you group your sequence of words into groups of words that have the same number of characters, than you have a group of words with just one character and a group of words with two characters, one with three characters etc.

The Key is the thing you used to group on. So the key is the first letter or the word, or he number of letters in the word when you grouped on number of characters.

You can use the key to identify the group. So if you want the group with words that start with the letter 'h', you say you want the element of your group sequence that has a key equal to 'h'. If you grouped on number of characters you can ask for the group with key 4 to get all four letter words.

Group keys are unique. You may be certain there is only one such an element, so you can ask for the first (or default if there is no such group)

Example: download the book Iliad by Homer, and split the result into a sequence of words:

```
var uri = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/6130/6130-0.txt";
var iliadWords = new String(
     new WebClient().DownloadString(uri)
        .Select(token => char.IsLetter(token) ? token : ' ')
        .ToArray())
        .Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var wordsGroupedByFirstLetter = iliadWords
    .GroupBy(word => word.FirstOrDefault());

IEnumerable<string> allWordsStartingWithX = wordsGroupedByFirstLetter
    .FirstOrDefault(group => group.key == 'X');
```

Comment: very good explanation. To sum up, `Key` is simply a variable name representing the WHOLE group by thingy. Unlike the SQL world I'm coming from, LINQ is OO, everything is object, property, methods, etc. In order to refer to something inside of the group by, we have to do `Key.` syntactically. Question, I've seen **GroupBy** and **group xyz by**. What's the difference?

Comment: Linq comes in two flavors: method syntax, where every function is a method, and query syntax, using several keywords. Those who dream in OO languages prefer Method syntax, those who come from DB Query world, like SQL are more familiar with query syntax. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx. The advantage of the method syntax is that you can extend linq by creating your own extension methods. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx